# Something = Something = Something... What?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading some code and I see a comparison that's laid out like this:

`a = b = c`

Seeing as how searching Javascript about equal or comparison yields remedial results, anyone care to explain what's going on?

EDIT:  These are all objects or object properties that we're talking about here, should have specified.

DOUBLE EDIT: This is inside of an Object.defineProperties() block.

Comment: Note that `=` is not the same as `==`. The first is assignment, the later is comparison. The code you gave uses only assignment, not comparison.

Comment: I realized this after I posted.  Just gonna remove the code to avoid trolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `=` operator associates right-to-left and evaluates to the value that was assigned.

So this:

```
a = b = c;
```

Means this*:

```
b = c;
a = c;
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Unless you're dealing with properties.</sub>

Comment: I'm actually dealing with objects and their properties rather than simple variables.

Comment: @user23875: I meant dynamic properties. You are almost certainly not dealing with those.

Comment: Yep, I am.  Technically this is inside an Object.defineProperties() block.

Comment: @user23875: Whoa. Okay. So it's *actually* not equivalent to anything except itself.

Comment: Good enough for government work.  Gonna just call in the heavies and ask the guy who coded this, haha.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is an operator. It takes two arguments: a variable reference and an expression. It assigns the value of the expression to the variable, and returns the assigned value.

As a result, you can chain them and it equates to this:

```
a = (b = c)
```

In other words, assign `b` to the value of `c`, then assign that value to `a` also.

Answer (score 4):

`a = b = c` is just shorthand expression for:

```
b = c;
a = b;
```

`if(a = b)` will always return `true` because it is assigning, instead of comparing. To compare, the statement should read: `if(a == b)`.

Comment: Not strictly true, it's more like `b=c; a=c;` - the two are completely equivalent, of course, but `=` "returns" the assigned value.

Comment: `if(a = b)` wouldn't always be `true`. If `b` is falsy, `a = b` is falsy.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a comparison. It is an assignment of the value of `c` to the `b` and `a` variables.

Assignment works right to left, so it is an assignment of `c` to `b` first. Then the return value of that operation is assigned to `a`.

The return value of an assignment operation is the value that was assigned, so `a` will get the same value assigned to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

It equates this;

```
b = c; a = b;
```